# Is there a way of getting this font to work on my website?

Tags: css, fonts

I was browsing a website earlier with a family of fonts that I didn't recognise as being available for web.

You can view them on this page http://www.etq-amsterdam.com/collection/mid-1-white

According to inspect element, the fonts are:

```
@font-face {
font-family:AvenirNextLTPro-Demi;
src:url(fonts/28C41E_0_0.eot);
src:url(fonts/28C41E_0_0.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(fonts/28C41E_0_0.woff)format("woff"),url(fonts/28C41E_0_0.ttf) format("truetype") }

@font-face {
font-family:AvenirNextLTPro-Regular;
src:url(fonts/28C41E_1_0.eot);
src:url(fonts/28C41E_1_0.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),url(fonts/28C41E_1_0.woff) format("woff"),url(fonts/28C41E_1_0.ttf) format("truetype") }
```

I tried using the "font-family:AvenirNextLTPro-Regular;" line as I would do with other typefaces but it didn't work. Is this easily achievable or are they likely to have bought a license to use the font (if that's even possible)?

Comment: something about using `@font-face`: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've tried the codes on that site but I haven't managed to get it to work yet. All of the correct files have been uploaded via FTP to my sites root folder, but there's no change on my site at all.

Answer (score 3):

The font-face tag loads the fonts from files, in this case, from `http://www.etq-amsterdam.com/css/fonts/28C41E_0_0.woff`, so you would need to also have those fonts loaded on your server in order to access them from the CSS